# how to keep windows media player playing when output is disconnected

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

I use the output to troubleshoot things, so prefer that the output keeps going - how to override the WMP stopping playback when the output wire is disconnected??

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to play into an amplified speaker, then use the headphone output of the speaker for your troubleshooting signal.  That way, when you unplug the line to the unit you're working on, the computer will still see the output connected, and keep happily playing.